# onloadedmetadata callback for Audio?

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling, dom-events

If I have the following code, then the callback function gets called:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
    console.log("Loaded metadata for %s, duration=%s",
                soundUrl, audio.duration);
    audio = null;
});
audio.src = soundUrl;
```

However, if I do the following, the callback doesn't get called:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.onloadedmetadata = function () {
    console.log("Loaded metadata for %s, duration=%s",
                soundUrl, audio.duration);
    audio = null;
};
audio.src = soundUrl;
```

Is there any good reason for this? I thought `FOO.addEventListener(BAR, BAZ)` was equivalent to `FOO['on' + BAR] = BAZ`.

Comment: I agree it feels like 2nd example should work, but MDN example also uses `addEventListener`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not in this case although I believe both approaches should have the same effect. It may be the case that the audio is loaded faster before your script gets a chance to run and fire the event.

I've browsed some but could only find examples with adding an addEventListener. This article on dev.opera.com sheds some light on it although it's about video http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/consistent-event-firing-with-html5-video/